# Sound fader control source select

Tags: audio, source

I'm trying to add second source to an amplifier. It uses TEA6320t sound fader control chip which takes in multiple sources and outputs one.

> The source selector selects one of 4 stereo inputs or the
>   mono input.

Currently only one input is used, but the question is how to change form one source to another? Here's the  [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TEA6320.pdf) of the chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. TEA6320T block diagram.*

The data sheet block diagram leaves you with only three non-audio pins. Rule out the MUTE input and you're left with SCL and SDA, the I\$^2\$C-bus.

Table 8 shows the I\$^2\$C-bus input selection table.

[image]